# Call implementation class based on conditions

Tags: java, initialization

I've a one interface and its multiple implementations.

On the basis of conditions, I need to call specific implementation.

**Example:**

```
@Autowired
MyProcessor1 myProcessor1;

@Autowired
MyProcessor2 myProcessor2;
....


Map<ActionTuple, List<EmpList>> tupledEmpMap = empList.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(emp -> new ActionTuple(emp.getAction(), emp.getPriority())));

tupledEmpMap.forEach((tuple, empList) -> {
    MyProcessorInterface processor = null;
    if (tuple.isActionPriority("ADD", "HIGH")) {
        processor = myProcessor1;
    } else if (tuple.isActionPriority("ADD", "LOW")) {
        processor = myProcessor2;
    } else if (condition3) {
        processor = myProcessor3;
    } else if (condition4) {
        processor = myProcessor4;
    }
    processor.execute();
}
```

I was thinking if we can shorthand multiple `if` conditions.

Please suggest.

Comment: Specify the conditions, in detail. Can the processors implement a `boolean canHandle` method or some other method indicating what they handle? How else do they differ?

Comment: Okay, I think I have a handle on this question: Is it that this class's single responsibility is to route actions to the appropriate processors based on conditions? If so, it appears that you  _do_ have working code, and in general requests for improvement on working code should go on Code Review (of course, review their On-Topic rules). I have an idea, and feel free to post over there and tag me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use strategy design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Spring, you can always use `@Configuration` classes and inject your dependencies based on some parameters in the configuration classes themselves. You'll get rid of the if-statement-based field assignment and you'll only ever have to inject (autowire) a single interface.